# Jquery variables only store limited data

Tags: jquery, variables

I never knew this would happen but I think I've reached the limit of how much a variable declared using JQuery can store.

I'm using this code to save all the content inside a div and store in my database.
`var format = $('#parent').html();`

In the html inside `#parent` there are base64 images and some text.

When I `INSERT` the data into my database it only shows half of the content inside `#parent`.

I have all my columns set to `TEXT` inside table and I'm going to try to set to `LONG TEXT` but I'm sure the content I'm trying to save isn't more than 64K...

Comment: If you are going to try `LONG TEXT` anyway, couldn't you have tried it before asking - just in case?

Answer (score 1):

64K can actually go by really quickly, especially if you have a table, and double-especially with base64 embedded images.

Try changing to a LONGTEXT. If that works, then that was your problem.